# When to use this construction: so Adjective a Noun

Tags: syntactic-analysis, adjective-position

In "The Quiet American" by Graham Greene, Mr Fowler says:

> I watched her closely while she asked how I was and touched my splinted leg and gave me her shoulder to lean on, as though one could lean with safety on **so young a plant**.

From what I learned in school, I would have written: "such a young plant", but apparently "so Adjective a Noun" is correct English.

What is the name of the construction above (if there is one)?
When is it used?

Comment: _Such (a)_ `Noun Phrase`, but _so_ `Adjective` _a_ `Noun`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know if it has a formal name, but it's used not infrequently in more formal writing.

> - But his hand fell to his side as though he could not bear the exertion of even *so small a gesture*.
> - This is not *so grand a gesture* on my part. It is mostly an admission of defeat.
> - They said that it stood for “able,” *so strong a woman* was Hester Prynne.
> - The Master, weary from his own shower of blows, and fearing nothing from *so weak a man*, dropped his hand for an instant, and at that instant...
> - As such, their lifespans are ridiculously long for *so tiny a creature*: up to 30 years (if that doesn’t sound high to you, consider that British men in the Middle Ages had the same life expectancy, and probably did the same amount of toiling in mud). (of a naked mole rat, Wired, 9/12/14)

It's not an unusual construction, and carries a bit more impact than "such a **_ _**" because of its less common construction.

Answer (score 9):

The structure *so + adjective* is normally only found used predicatively, where it appears as the complement of a verb:

- The music was so beautiful.

Here we see *so beautiful* appearing as the complement of the verb *BE*. We cannot usually use this structure attributively to modify a noun after the indefinite article, *a*, or when there is zero article:

- It was so beautiful music. * (wrong)
- It was a so beautiful song. * (wrong)

In these instances we need *such* instead of *so*:

- It was such beautiful music.
- It was such a beautiful song.

Notice that while *so* modifies the adjective, *such* modifies the whole noun phrase. We could just as easily use no adjective at all:

- It was such a song!

*Such* then can be regarded as a strange kind of word (perhaps determiner, perhaps adverb, perhaps adjective), which modifies the whole Noun Phrase, including the article. Notice too that we say *Such a beautiful song* and not *a such beautiful song*. We cannot use *such* to grammatically modify an adjective in that way. *Such* definitely modifies noun phrases not adjectives.

However, an alternative way of achieving the same kind of effect as either of methods above is to use [so + adjective] *before* the indefinite article:

- It was so beautiful a song ...

Here, in this position before the indefinite article, we *can* use the adverb *so* with an adjective. Here it is modifying the adjective *beautiful*. This time the adjective itself, very unusually, modifies the whole Noun Phrase including the article. This gives it quite a literary effect. It is not what we would regard as everyday, informal, conversational English although it is common in descriptive writing.

Comment: Does `so` here mean very or anything demonstrates many? i.e so big, so far, so long

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a reordered construction of

> ... as though one could lean with safety on a plant *that is so young*.

*[So](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/so#so)*, in this sense means

> Extremely; very much (used for emphasis): *she looked so pretty*

An alternative construction could be

> ... as though one could lean with safety on a plant *so young*.

In each case, the phrase is an adjectival modifier of *plant*.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know where this grammar point is treated in grammars by English authors. I have to look it up. In grammars by German authors this is treated in the chapter definite and indefinite article.

Normally the word order is article + adjective + noun. In special cases English uses a different order:
The definite article is in post-postion after all, both, double, half, quite, twice
as in:

all the children, both your hands, double the amount, quite the best film, half the loaf, twice the length

The indefinite article is in post-position after half, quite, rather, such, what (exclamation) as in
half a loaf (derived from: the half of a loaf), quite/rather a surprise,
What a man!

The indefinite article is in post-position when adjectives are modified by as ...as,
so, too, how, however as in

so difficult a task, too slow a run.

In the Longman Grammar of English by L.G. Alexander you find it only by using the register (too clever a  man) and he has only one example and does not give a survey about this grammar point.

I have never seen a name for structures of the type "so young a girl", but I would put it in the box "special positions of adjectives".