# Too big a step?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am recently reading a book called "Small Steps". So there is one sentence I just came across, which was "If he tried to take **too big a step**,...", I thought this sentence was grammatically wrong, but if it is, the author will not have written it. Right?

Please tell me why "too big a step", or simply "too (adj.) a (noun)" is correct and how to form a sentence like this, I would like to try using new phrases in my essays.

Thank you very much! xx

Comment: Hello, Furby. Welcome to ELU. There is another discussion on this site [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196784/when-to-use-this-construction-so-adjective-a-noun)  which deals with the same kind of construction as "too big a...". In this case, it uses "so". You might be interested.

Comment: There are certain combinations of adverb + adjective that are placed  before the indefinite article. Any grammar will inform you about such things or google it.

Comment: I note that you label "too" as an adjective when its an adverb, which modify verbs, adverbs and adjectives. "He tried to take "too step..." would be grammatically wrong, for there the adverb is trying to modify a noun. But the original construction  where an adverb modifies an adjective is fine.